# How do I use Alexa's Dialogue Directives in Java?

Tags: java, alexa-skills-kit

There is barely any information online that I can find in relation to this topic.
I dont know how to access intents, or use them to return a response given certain parameters are met with that intent. Im trying to create a dialogue that can be as simple as,

Me: "Add a unit"

Alexa: "What shoult the unit be called?"

Me: "Engineering"

Alexa: "Ok, added the unit Engineering."

Currently all I know how to do is perform an action once the skill is called upon, regardless of what is said. So for example, I could literally say,

Me: "Alexa, open StudyPal"

Alexa: "Something that is returned whenever the skill is activated"

or...

Me: "Alexa, ask StudyPal about my units"

Alexa: "Something that is returned whenever the skill is activated"

Any help would be appreciated. For reference, this is some of my code...

```
public class StudyPalHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
private final Skill skill;
private final JacksonSerializer serializer;

public StudyPalHandler() {
    skill = new StandardSkillBuilder()
            .addRequestHandler(new StudyPalExtraHandler())
            .build();
    serializer = new JacksonSerializer();
}

@Override
public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
    String request = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
    RequestEnvelope requestEnvelope = serializer.deserialize(request, RequestEnvelope.class);
    ResponseEnvelope responseEnvelope = skill.invoke(requestEnvelope);
    byte[] response = serializer.serialize(responseEnvelope).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    outputStream.write(response);
}
}

public class StudyPalExtraHandler implements RequestHandler {
@Override
public boolean canHandle(HandlerInput handlerInput) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Optional<Response> handle(HandlerInput handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.getResponseBuilder().withSpeech("Something that is returned whenever the skill is activated").build();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `canHandle()` method of the associated handler class to check whether that particular handler can handle that request.

Ex: If you want handle a `StudyPalIntent`, then

```
public class StudyPalIntentHandler implements RequestHandler {

@Override
public boolean canHandle(HandlerInput input) {
    return input.matches(intentName("StudyPalIntent"));
}

@Override
public Optional<Response> handle(HandlerInput input) {
    return input.getResponseBuilder()
            .withSpeech("your response speech here")
            .withReprompt("your re prompt here")              
            .build();
}
```

From the sdk source code you can use dialog diretives like this

```
return input.getResponseBuilder()
   .withSpeech("your response speech here")
   .withReprompt("your re prompt here") 
   .addDelegateDirective(updatedIntent)              
   .build();
```

Other dialog directives helper methods are

```
addElicitSlotDirective(String slotName, Intent updatedIntent)
addConfirmSlotDirective(String slotName, Intent updatedIntent)
addConfirmIntentDirective(Intent updatedIntent)
```

Check this [ResponseBuilder.java](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-java/blob/2.0.x/ask-sdk-core/src/com/amazon/ask/response/ResponseBuilder.java) class